# Alternating colors in listview but needs to have a starting color

Tags: android, listview, colors

I have a listview that looks like this.

```
| Header |
----------
| Data 1 |
----------
| Data 2 |
----------
| Data 3 |
----------
| Header |
----------
| Data 1 |
----------
| Header |
----------
| Data 1 |
----------
| Data 2 |
----------
| Data 3 |
----------
| Data 4 |
----------
```

and here is my code when im putting some colors on alternating rows

```
\\My view
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  /* Alternating Colors*/
    LinearLayout line_others = v.findViewById(R.id.line_others);

    if (position % 2 == 0) {
        line_others.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
    } else {                         
        line_others.setBackgroundResource(R.color.alt_gray);
    }
}
```

and this is the output

```
| Header |
----------
| Data 1 | GRAY
----------
| Data 2 | RED
----------
| Data 3 | GRAY
----------
| Header |
----------
| Data 1 | RED
----------
| Header |
----------
| Data 1 | RED
----------
| Data 2 | GRAY
----------
| Data 3 | RED
----------
| Data 4 | GRAY
----------
```

Actually it is working but i need to achieve something. I need to start with color red for every first row in a group something like this.

```
| Header |
----------
| Data 1 | RED
----------
| Data 2 | GRAY
----------
| Data 3 | RED
----------
| Header |
----------
| Data 1 | RED
----------
| Header |
----------
| Data 1 | RED
----------
| Data 2 | GRAY
----------
| Data 3 | RED
----------
| Data 4 | GRAY
----------
```

My question is how can I achieve that? thanks

Updated

`ItemModel.java`

```
public class ItemModel implements Comparable<ItemModel> {
    private boolean isSectionHeader;
    private String cusname;
    private String date;
}

public String getCusname() {
    return cusname;
}

public void setCusname(String cusname) {
    this.cusname = cusname;
}

public boolean isSectionHeader() {
    return isSectionHeader;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(ItemModel itemModel) {
    return this.date.compareTo(itemModel.date);
}

public void setToSectionHeader() {
    isSectionHeader = true;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getRemarks() {
    return remarks;
}


public ItemModel(String cusname, String remarks, String date) {
        this.isSectionHeader = isSectionHeader;
        this.cusname = cusname;
        this.remarks = remarks;
        this.date = date;
}
```

This where I transfer my data from sqllite to array

```
private ArrayList<ItemModel> getItems() {
    Cursor data = myDb.get_plan(pattern_email);
    ArrayList<ItemModel> items = new ArrayList<>();
    while (data.moveToNext()) {
        String cusname = data.getString(0);
        String remarks = data.getString(2);
        String date = data.getString(3);
        items.add(new ItemModel(cusname, remarks, date));
    }
    return items;
}
```

Here is the sorter and display in listview

```
private ArrayList sortAndAddSections(ArrayList<ItemModel> itemList) {

    ArrayList<ItemModel> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> tmpHeaderPositions = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.sort(itemList);
    ItemModel sectionCell;

    String header = "";
    int addedRow = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
        if (!(header.equals(itemList.get(i).getDate()))) {
            String cusname = itemList.get(i).getCusname();
            String remarks = itemList.get(i).getRemarks();
            sectionCell = new ItemModel(cusname, remarks, date);
            sectionCell.setToSectionHeader();
            tmpHeaderPositions.add(i + addedRow);
            addedRow++;
            tempList.add(sectionCell);
            header = itemList.get(i).getDate();
        }
        tempList.add(itemList.get(i));
    }

    tmpHeaderPositions.add(tempList.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < tmpHeaderPositions.size() - 1; i++) {
        sectionCell = tempList.get(tmpHeaderPositions.get(i));
        sectionCell.setDate(sectionCell.getDate() + " (" +
                (tmpHeaderPositions.get(i + 1) - tmpHeaderPositions.get(i) - 1) + ")");
    }
    return tempList;
}
```

and here is my view

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  /* Alternating Colors*/
    LinearLayout line_others = v.findViewById(R.id.line_others);

    if (position % 2 == 0) {
        line_others.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
    } else {                         
        line_others.setBackgroundResource(R.color.alt_gray);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy, when you build your data , add a new attribute like 'order', then build like this:

Assuming your class model:

```
        DataEntry {

          int order;
          ... 
        }


        addHeader 1
        addDataEntry(order: 1)
        addDataEntry(order: 2)
        addDataEntry(order: 3)
        addDataEntry(order: ... n)

        addHeader 2
        addDataEntry(order: 1)
        addDataEntry(order: 2)
        addDataEntry(order: 3)
        addDataEntry(order: ... n)

        ...

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
      /* Alternating Colors*/
                        DataEntry entry = list.get(position);
                        LinearLayout line_others = v.findViewById(R.id.line_others);
                        if (entry.position % 2 == 0) {
                            line_others.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
                        } else {
                            line_others.setBackgroundResource(R.color.alt_gray);
                        }
    }
```

Comment: sorry but i didnt where the `DateEntry` came from. I hope you gave me a must simplified code

Comment: I have a class with `getter` and `setter`

Comment: Yes that could be your dataentry a order attribute

Comment: maybe just a little explanation from how you create the class until i used that in my color. All i need is an alternating color but it needs to start with red in every group

Comment: You didn't show us how you build your data so we don't know

Comment: Is very easy, just add a counter every time you start adding items on each header

Comment: how can i achieve that?

Comment: sorry bro, your issue is about the logic , not android.

Comment: i hope theres a better way to this