# Alternating colors in Listview

Tags: android, android-studio, listview, listviewitem

In my listview `getView` i have a code like this

`if (position % 2 == 0) {
    v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
}`

and this is the out put of that

[image]

but what if the data looks like this

[image]

I tried the code above but it looks like this

[image]

but i need to is like this.

[image]

I dont know whats wrong but the color pattern exchange every group. How can I fix it based on the last format. Always starts with blue

Updated

`ItemModel.java`

```
public class ItemModel implements Comparable<ItemModel> {
    private boolean isSectionHeader;
    private String cusname;
    private String date;
}

public String getCusname() {
    return cusname;
}

public void setCusname(String cusname) {
    this.cusname = cusname;
}

public boolean isSectionHeader() {
    return isSectionHeader;
}

@Override
public int compareTo(ItemModel itemModel) {
    return this.date.compareTo(itemModel.date);
}

public void setToSectionHeader() {
    isSectionHeader = true;
}

public String getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(String date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public String getRemarks() {
    return remarks;
}


public ItemModel(String cusname, String remarks, String date) {
        this.isSectionHeader = isSectionHeader;
        this.cusname = cusname;
        this.remarks = remarks;
        this.date = date;
}
```

This where I transfer my data from sqllite to array

```
private ArrayList<ItemModel> getItems() {
    Cursor data = myDb.get_plan(pattern_email);
    ArrayList<ItemModel> items = new ArrayList<>();
    while (data.moveToNext()) {
        String cusname = data.getString(0);
        String remarks = data.getString(2);
        String date = data.getString(3);
        items.add(new ItemModel(cusname, remarks, date));
    }
    return items;
}
```

Here is the sorter and display in listview

```
private ArrayList sortAndAddSections(ArrayList<ItemModel> itemList) {

    ArrayList<ItemModel> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Integer> tmpHeaderPositions = new ArrayList<>();
    Collections.sort(itemList);
    ItemModel sectionCell;

    String header = "";
    int addedRow = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
        if (!(header.equals(itemList.get(i).getDate()))) {
            String cusname = itemList.get(i).getCusname();
            String remarks = itemList.get(i).getRemarks();
            sectionCell = new ItemModel(cusname, remarks, date);
            sectionCell.setToSectionHeader();
            tmpHeaderPositions.add(i + addedRow);
            addedRow++;
            tempList.add(sectionCell);
            header = itemList.get(i).getDate();
        }
        tempList.add(itemList.get(i));
    }

    tmpHeaderPositions.add(tempList.size());
    for (int i = 0; i < tmpHeaderPositions.size() - 1; i++) {
        sectionCell = tempList.get(tmpHeaderPositions.get(i));
        sectionCell.setDate(sectionCell.getDate() + " (" +
                (tmpHeaderPositions.get(i + 1) - tmpHeaderPositions.get(i) - 1) + ")");
    }
    return tempList;
}
```

and here is my view

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
  /* Alternating Colors*/
    LinearLayout line_others = v.findViewById(R.id.line_others);

    if (position % 2 == 0) {
        line_others.setBackgroundResource(R.color.red);
    } else {                         
        line_others.setBackgroundResource(R.color.alt_gray);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following is based on the answer here: [Alternating colors in listview but needs to have a starting color](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51699118/alternating-colors-in-listview-but-needs-to-have-a-starting-color)

1. Add a new int field, bgColor, in **ItemModel** and create getter and setter methods.
2. Change:

   ```
   private ArrayList sortAndAddSections(ArrayList<ItemModel> itemList) {

       ArrayList<ItemModel> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
       ArrayList<Integer> tmpHeaderPositions = new ArrayList<>();
       Collections.sort(itemList);
       ItemModel sectionCell;

       String header = "";
       int addedRow = 0;
       int bgColor = R.color.red; //Added
       for (int i = 0; i < itemList.size(); i++) {
           if (!(header.equals(itemList.get(i).getDate()))) {
               String cusname = itemList.get(i).getCusname();
               String remarks = itemList.get(i).getRemarks();
               sectionCell = new ItemModel(cusname, remarks, date);
               sectionCell.setToSectionHeader();
               tmpHeaderPositions.add(i + addedRow);
               addedRow++;
               tempList.add(sectionCell);
               header = itemList.get(i).getDate();
               bgColor = R.color.red; //Added
           }
           sectionCell = itemList.get(i); //Added
           sectionCell.setBgColor(bgColor); //Added
           tempList.add(sectionCell); //Changed
           if (bgColor == R.color.red) bgColor = R.color.alt_gray; //Added
           else bgColor = R.color.red; //Added
       }

       tmpHeaderPositions.add(tempList.size());
       for (int i = 0; i < tmpHeaderPositions.size() - 1; i++) {
       sectionCell = tempList.get(tmpHeaderPositions.get(i));
       sectionCell.setDate(sectionCell.getDate() + " (" +
           (tmpHeaderPositions.get(i + 1) - tmpHeaderPositions.get(i) - 1) + ")");
       }
       return tempList;
   }
   ```
3. Change adapter getView(). No more calculation for background color, just set it with bgColor from data item.

Hope that helps!

Comment: tysm. I will try this TYSM

Answer (score 1):

Have an int variable called counter or something and set that to 0 at the start of the code and whenever there is a new header.

Then for each line increment the counter by one and if the counter is an even number make the background blue.

ie.

```
counter = 0;

for each item in the list view {


if (isHeader) {

    counter  = 0;

} else {

    if (counter % 2 = 0) {

        background = blue;

    } 
    else {

        background = white;

    }
    counter++;
}

}
```

Comment: i tried what you said but it only gave me the color blue